# Slim framework - php - how prevent injections?

Tags: php, android, security, sql-injection, slim

As an android developer I would like prepare my server for request from android app. First aim was to create request link for adding items into database. So I have created something like that below in php file by Slim framwork.

**My question is**: is there any chance to inject "bad text" which would cause drop by database or do something less worse by calling `/addEntry`? How could I prevent this?

p.s I hope you follow me what I mean to say.

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader(); 

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get(
    '/',
    function () {
        echo "working";
    }
);

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

$username = ;
$password = ;
$hostname = ;
$database = ;

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

if (!mysql_select_db($database)) {
    die("not connected");
}

//#addEntry
$app->post(
    '/addEntry',
    function () {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $cat_id = $app->request()->post('cat_id');
        $ent_name = $app->request()->post('ent_name');
        $ent_description = $app->request()->post('ent_description');

        if ($cat_id == NULL || $ent_name == NULL) {
            $app->halt(400);
        }

        mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
        mysql_query("insert into t_entries VALUES(NULL, '" . $ent_name . "', " 
                . (empty($ent_description) ? "NULL" : "'". $ent_description ."'")
                . "," . $cat_id . ", '0' );");

        return;
    }
);

$app->run();

$app->run();
```

Comment: You should escape user input if framework you use doesn't have built in that kind of protection.  Read about sql injections, there are lot of examples. Also mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: Look up `mysql_real_escape_string()` as a stop-gap until you can switch libraries. If you pass all user input that will be injected into SQL through this function, you will be OK. Parameter binding is still the way to go though!

Comment: Aside: why call `$app->run()` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use some existing ORM like Doctrine or Eloquent. Then you don't have to worry so much about user input as they are doing all hard work for you.

If you still want to use native php functions, don't use `mysql_connect()` as it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_connect()` instead. To prevent sql injections, use `mysqli_prepare()` to prepare SQL queries.

Also, you don't have to do this:

```
$app->post('/addEntry',function () {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
```

you can pass variables to closures with `use` keyword like this:

```
$app->post('/addEntry',function () use ($app) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use php function filter_var to sanitize input value. In Addition To this, I suggest to use ORM, such as RedBean or Eloquent or Doctrine. If you want to be more light try to use some librarym such as [Dabble](https://github.com/nramenta/dabble) or [Medoo](http://medoo.in/). Finally, I suggest to don't use php native functions.